# Creating html tables in R using the tab_model function

Tags: r, html-table

Hi I am Matthew and I currently recreate the statistics of a scientific paper.
In order to get nice html tables I use the function `tab_model`, which so far worked well for me since I only considered linear models (`lm()`)
However now I need to insert some additional rows consisting of characters or numbers, that are not part of a linear model.

Here my code: Sorry for the bad structure I am very new to R.

All the reg's are regressions I created with the `lm()` function.

```
Table3 <- tab_model(reg31, reg32, reg33, reg34, reg35, reg36, show.ci = F, show.intercept = F, digits = 2, 
                collapse.se = T, show.p = F, title = " Average Impacts of Saving Technologies after 12 Months", 
                string.est = " ", string.pred = " ", string.intercept = "Constant", 
                dv.labels = c("(1)", "(2)", "(3)", "(4)", "(5)", "(6)"), 
                pred.labels = c("Constant", "(P1) Safe Box", "(P2) Lockedbox", "(P3) Health Pot", "(P4) Health Savings"),
                rm.terms = c("multitreat", "dummy_strata2", "dummy_strata3", "dummy_strata4", 
                "dummy_strata5", "dummy_strata6", "dummy_strata6", "dummy_strata7", "dummy_strata8", "dummy_strata9", 
                "dummy_strata10", "dummy_strata11", "dummy_strata13", "dummy_strata15", "dummy_strata16", "dummy_strata20", 
                "bg_b1_age", "bg_female", "bg_married", "bg_provider", "bg_hyperbolic", "bg_pat_now_impat_later", 
                "bg_max_discount", "bg_n_roscas"))
```

This gives me a table with 5 rows, but I would like to add another one beneath them containing characters.

```
Individual_controls <- c("No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes")
```

I was wondering whether I have to create the table using a different function or if it is possible to insert or change the class of the Individual_controls vector somehow.

This is how the output should look:
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So I found a function called stargazer doing exactly what i was looking for.
I really recommend it.

Comment: Hi and thank you for answering your own question, we massively promote self learning and development here. However I'm not sure if your answer is very useful for any future readers with the same problem. Could you please give us some indication where you found this function you recommend, and how we could find it if needed?